# How to write a basic ETL using SQL without truncate/load at each ETL run?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I have a OLTP database which I am loading into another database using SQL (ETL). For this, in the 2nd database database I have created the star schema model based on facts and dimensions.

Technology: MS-SQL

Fact: Sales

Dimensions: Customer, Client, Agent

Note: There is no date modified field in the source system, and rows can be deleted in the source system.

I have a agent job that runs every 15 minutes to do the following: For each table, I am loading the data from OLTP db into the respective staging tables (for each dimension and fact table). Then merging the staging dim table into the dim table. Then updating the staging fact table to include the surrogate key of the dimension. Then using merge to sync the staging fact table with the fact table. This is resource consuming because I have to load entire data into the staging tables at each etl run. So I am looking for a better way - if someone can point me to how its done it will help me.

Comment: You have no state change data for a records.  You have no key identified which has a guaranteed non-reuse.  so you can't track deletions/insertions which may/maynot have same value.  You could add a trigger to the table and a timestamp field to keep track of updates, and have a deletions table which gets added to by trigger for deletions.  Then use this new column and table to track state changes; but this requires changes to source system.

Comment: You said `You have no key identified which has a guaranteed non-reuse. `. The source system tables have auto increment primary keys so this guarantees non-resuse.

Comment: Ok.  So then I'm back to trigger for update a column timestamp when change/Create occurs.   Pull all changes since last run timestamp.  Trigger for deletions.    Then your ETL is two steps: 1) pull anything with timestamp >= last run and merge.  2) Pull all deletions with timestamp >= last run and delete from target.    have to record last run date/time in ETL and update when complete..  Since there's an identity; we don't have to worry about edge cases with identity reuse

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot alter the source database. So cannot write a trigger or alter the table schema. So is my current approach the best possible?

Comment: You have no means of identifying a change state; so your basically deleting all data and pulling all data in each time.  I personally see no other way unless you could [merge replicate](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) the database to something you have control over; or though [log shipping](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and establish change state information and then base your ETL off the replica/secondary database...

Comment: The advantage of the secondary database is reporting could be doen against it instead of the primary allowing for less impact on the primary system.  The disadvantage is you have a delay depending on the timing of log/ships/replication..  so data isn't real time; though it can get very close.  you also have the added costs of maintaining a second instance of a database. and the infrastructure necessary to do so.  And then there's the data security risks... So this option can't be taken lightly.

Comment: @xQbert - suppose there is a key which has a guaranteed non-reuse, then what is the approach?

Answer (score 1):

> This is resource consuming because I have to load entire data into the staging tables at each etl run

1. Turn on [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Change Data Capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) at the source and extract only the changed rows

or

2. Create a readable replica on the DW server with [Transactional Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) from the source to the staging tables or using [Read-Scale Replica](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/configure-read-scale-availability-groups?view=sql-server-ver15) or [Log Shipping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/log-shipping/about-log-shipping-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Have I understood it correctly that the 2nd point only prevents the network transfer during each ETL runs and that I will still need to do the truncate and load?

Comment: You can MERGE from the replica to the data mart.